# Delegate in c++ (or something like this)

Tags: c++, delegates

In C++, i have:

```
//Base1.h
#ifndef BASE1_H
#define BASE1_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Base2.h"

using namespace std;

class Base1{
    private:
        string name;
    public:
        Base1(string _name);
        void printSomething();
        string getName();
};
#endif
```

In `Base1.cpp` i implement constructor `Base1(string _name)` and `string getName()` as normal, and the `printSomething()`:

```
void Base1::printSomething(){
    Base2 b2;
    // how to pass a parameter in the following code?
    b2.printBase1();
}

// This is Base2.h
#ifndef BASE2_H
#define BASE2_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Base1.h"

using namespace std;

class Base2{
    public:
      Base2();
      void printBase1(Base1 b);
};
#endif
```

And `Base2()` constructor i implement as usual, this is my `printBase1(Base1 b)`:

```
void Base2::printBase1(Base1 b){
    cout << b.getName();
}
```

So, in the end, i want to use `printSomething()` in `Base1` class, but i don't know how to pass parameter to the `b2.printBase1()` in `printSomething()` as above in my code. is there anything like `b2.printBase1(this)` in C++? If not, can you give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `this` is a pointer in C++, you need to dereference it:

```
b2.printBase1(*this);
```

Note that you have circular includes, you should remove `#include "Base2.h"` from `Base1.h`. Also look into passing parameters by (`const`) reference, especially for non-POD types, otherwise you might not get the expected behavior.

For example, your signature is

```
void printBase1(Base1 b);
```

when you call it, you create a copy of the parameter in the function, and thus operating on a copy. You should change this to:

```
void printBase1(Base1& b);
```

or

```
void printBase1(const Base1& b); //if you don't change b
```

Pass by value only when you're certain you **need** a copy.

Comment: If i remove `Base2.h`, how can i create `Base2 b2;` `in printSomething()`? I got an error:(!

Comment: @Kingfisher you include it in the cpp file, not the header.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't change `void printBase1(Base1 b)`, I still get a right result! am i lucky?

Comment: recently I got an problem: `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Base1' to 'Base1 &'`? What is my problem? If i remove every `const`, it will work again!!

Comment: @Kingfisher You're trying modify a const object, that's the problem.